# How to install Azure PowerShell 1.0?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I followed this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0/

It ended up download the the WebPI 5.0, it installed Windows Azure PowerShell for VS automatically, does it include Azure PowerShell 1.0? Where is it installed? How can I start? I could only find the Windows PowerShell in “Start”, are they the same? I started the WebPI again, it said Azure PowerShell for VS is installed. I try to search with WebPI,   could only find Azure PowerShell 0.9 not 1.0

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installation, the Azure commands are available under Windows PowerShell, so that's indeed what you are looking for. There is no longer a separate Azure PowerShell Start menu entry.